# Endeca-Hybris integration not working

Tags: endeca, sap-commerce-cloud

i'am trying to integrate hybris 4.7.9 with endeca. I have installed the following endeca components. 1)MDEX engine 2)Platform services 3)Endeca workbench 4)CAS.

I have deployed a sample application on endeca side using "D:\Endeca\ToolsAndFrameworks\11.0.0\deployment_template\bin\deploy.bat"

In Hyend2 in admincockpit of hybris
I have made EAC/CAS connection with my appication and made a export job.

Problem is i am not able to run that job, it reports me following error:

```
    http://localhost:8500/MyAppen_en_data/?wsdl returned response code 404
    at com.endeca.itl.service.ServiceLocator.getService(ServiceLocator.java:150)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Hybris, but since the error is related to Endeca, let me try to give some pointers.

1. **CAS:**  Check that `CAS` is up and running
2. **App Name:**  You might have specified *app-name-with-locale* (`MyAppen`) somewhere where you need to specify only *app-name* (`MyApp`).  [The Endeca app name without the locale is called as "*Base Application Name*".  Go back and check all your configurations in Hybris and Endeca].

You may also refer to [this blog](http://atgendecaoasis.blogspot.in/2013/01/wsdl-returned-response-code-404.html) (Although it is for ATG framework, it should give idea for Hybris as well).